# Borrar Pdf en c#

Tags: c#

Cómo puedo borrar un archivo PDF una vez que cierro el documento? Alguien sabe como hacer esto en C#? Ahora ya tengo el código que me abre el PDF, pero quiero que al cerrar el PDF se borre automáticamente.

```
var pdfProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ruta);
```

Answer (score 2):

mediante **[Process.Exited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx)** y usando **[File.Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx)**, antes de eliminarlo asegura terminar el proceso:

```
pdfProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(pdfProcess_Exited);
void pdfProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)    {  
     pdfProcess.Kill(); //importante terminar el proceso!
     System.IO.File.Delete(ruta);
    }
```

Comment: sabes como cerrar una imagen en vez de un pdf. Es que me han dicho que no se puede y es cuestion de mi SO. Publicacion      http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60855/como-borrar-archivos-o-carpetas-en-uso-c