# ¿Como borrar archivos o carpetas en uso? C#

Tags: c#

Me gustaria saber la forma en que se deben de borrar mis carpetas dentro de mi aplicacion de C#, las imagenes que estan dentro de mis carpetas estan en uso, no todas solo algunas, asi que me gustaria saber como quitar ese uso o cerrar la imagen antes de eliminar para que cuando llegue al comando pueda hacer la eliminacion de forma correcta.

Codigo Actual:

```
    string directorio = @"..\..\Imagenes\Imagenes_Modal\Usuario\Abril";



    if (Directory.Exists(directorio)) {
        Directory.Delete(directorio,true);
    }
```

El error que me sale es el Siguiente:

> El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo 'Abril0.jpeg' porque
>   está siendo utilizado en otro proceso.

Comment: No se puede,  hasta donde sé el sistema operativo no te permitirá acceder, a menos que dejes de usarlo `(cerrar)`

Comment: Así es, eso es tema del SO, no de tu aplicación.

Comment: Eso quiere decir que ¿no hay forma de borrar archivos que se esten usando en mi aplicacion?, desde C#

Comment: @David ¿Por qué necesitas borrar la carpeta o archivo mientras está en uso?

Comment: No podras borrar archivos que tenga abiertos cualquier aplicacion, no solo la tuya, es algo que controla el S.O.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para poder eliminar un archivo debes trabajarlo sin que este sea bloqueado por la aplicacion, por ejemplo si la idea es mostrar este en un Picturebox usarias algo como ser

```
using (var stream = File.Open(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
   PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

la idea es que puedas lograr destruir el objeto que accede al archivo para que este no quede lockeado.

Desconozco que operacion realzias con el archivo, pero deberias analizar el codigo que implementaste y lograr introducir el `using` para que luego de la lectura el archivo sea liberado y puedas eliminarlo

Comment: si se pudo de esta forma, gracias por el apoyo